# How to create custom SBT console commands with Play Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, command-line-interface

The question is in the title:
Is it possible and how to create custom SBT console commands with Play Scala?
The idea is to have an CLI executable script that can use the whole project code.

I could not fine any documentation about it.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the marked question. The only answer there pertaining to Play 2 refers to _build_ tasks, not "app-management"-type tasks which, as the questioner states, have access to the project code.

Comment: I really have no idea what the OP is trying to do. Without a use case, I'll doubt he will be an answer.